How does one recognize an "official envoy" or "Chargé d’Affaires" or even an ambassador without recognizing a government?
14 Feb 2024:

At an official ceremony held by the Chinese government in Beijing on January 30, a queue of foreign diplomats lined up to present their credentials to President Xi Jinping. Among the 309 diplomats was an unlikely participant.
After over two years of negotiations, China recognised Bilal Karimi, a former Taliban spokesman, as an official envoy to Beijing [...]

Reportedly since then other countries followed suit.

August 27, 2024
Kazakhstan’s Foreign Ministry has officially recognized Taliban diplomat Mohammad Rahman Rahmani as the Chargé d’Affaires of the Afghan Embassy in Astana. [...]
Hours before Kazakhstan’s move, the United Arab Emirates accepted the credentials of a Taliban ambassador.

(I double checked that the latter [for UAE] has that title, and apparently he does).
It's quite understandable that Afghanistan's neighbors would agree to some level of relations with the Taliban. But I'm curious purely on the level of formalities, how does one recognize an "official envoy" or a "Chargé d’Affaires" without recognizing a government? (Reportedly, still nobody recognizes the Taliban as such.) An envoy/ambassador of whom?

My guess would be that formally this is just a mess. In practice this person is a) granted the privileges of an ambassador/ diplomat and b) is the contact person for any matters related to things on the territory of Afghanistan.

In these cases, it mostly matters what the Chinese and Khazaks do. It doesn't force other diplomats to recognize these persons. Yet, the ability to contact the Taliban indirectly can be worthwhile to other governments. Astana can be a good location to do so unnoticed.

I suggest it might be possible to recognise a 'Chargé d’Affaires' or any such person without recognising a government in only one case, which would rule out acknowledging any 'ambassador' or 'official envoy'.
My 'one case' is where other states recognise the nation without acknowledging a particular government.

Historical precedent: The Permanent Mission of the Federal Republic of Germany at the German Democratic Republic existed and played the role of an embassy ("equivalent to"), despite West Germany not recognizing East Germany as a foreign state. In this case, the trick was to change two words: "in" (in) to "at" (bei), and "pursuant" (gemäß) to "equivalent" (entsprechend).

A "Chargé d’Affaires" is a diplomatic official who temporarily takes the place of an ambassador.
Usually, this is due to a temporary vacancy in the post. But the analogy in this situation, I suppose, could be to a receiver, or trustee, or perhaps a regent for a hereditary office holder who is a child.
Effectively, Kazakhstan (as opposed to the Taliban government in Afghanistan) is appointing this individual (as a suitable individual, rather than as a regime appointee and regime representative) to look after the property of the former Afghan government in Kazakhstan and to look out for the best interests of Afghan nationals in the country (e.g. if they have run-ins with the criminal justice system there). But presumably without the authority to speak on behalf of the Taliban regime in Afghanistan in this case, until it is recognized formally.
This official would also, on an interim basis, probably have the authority to seek recognition for the Taliban regime by the government of Kazakhstan on the theory that doing so is in the best interests of the people of Afghan nationality who are in Kazakhstan, and would be expected to be a back channel of unofficial communication with the not yet recognized Taliban regime. If successful in the effort to get that regime formally recognized, that individual might be upgraded from being a chargé d’affaires to being the ambassador for Afghanistan in Kazakhstan.
In theory, one could even have a chargé d’affaires on this basis for a country like Somalia during the time that it didn't even have a de facto national government and was in a state of anarchy ruled by a mishmash of local warlords.
"Official envoy" in contrast, would suggest a person whose primary or sole official role is to discuss potential formal recognition of the Taliban regime and that the person is acting as an agent of that regime which is currently seen as just a non-governmental organization until it is recognized as the legitimate government of Afghanistan.
These functions can also be appointed by consuls of a third-party state on behalf of a state that doesn't have diplomatic relations with the receiving country or in cases where the sending country can't afford to send a diplomat of its own to handle the affairs of its nationals.
Of course, a complicating factor in this analysis is that the term "official envoy" in case of the People's Republic of China is really some Mandarin Chinese word that is being translated in that way, and likewise "chargé d’affaires" in the case of Kazakhstan is probably really a translation of some other word in the Kazakh language. So, there is great potential for a lost in translation moment between subtle shades of meaning between different terms in the receiving country's language.
This is especially the case because this is not a term with the same level of international standardization of an "ambassador" or a "consul" which are defined in the widely adopted Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations (1961), and the Vienna Convention on Consular Relations (1963), which has been used on a regular basis in the diplomatic circles of almost every country for decades and codifies practices and terminology that was widely used long before the Convention was adopted. These terms have a well established meaning in most official languages of receiving countries. But some languages may have no regular word for this kind of position, and officials in those countries may be making it up as the go.
Relevant Treaty Provisions
In support of this analysis, Article 2(3) of the Vienna Convention on Consular Relations (1963) linked below states:

The severance of diplomatic relations shall not ipso facto involve the
severance of consular relations.

Article 14(1) of the 1961 Convention states that:

Heads of mission are divided into three classes, namely: (a) That of
ambassadors or nuncios accredited to Heads of State, and other heads
of mission of equivalent rank; (b) That of envoys, ministers and
internuncios accredited to Heads of State; [and] (c) That of chargés
d’affaires accredited to Ministers for Foreign Affairs.

The 1961 Convention isn't entirely clear about the difference between a "ambassador" and an "envoy" except to establish that the envoy is inferior to an ambassador in matters of etiquette and prestige.
Article 19 of the 1961 Convention states that:


If the post of head of the mission is vacant, or if the head of the mission is unable to perform his functions a chargé d’affaires ad
interim shall act provisionally as head of the mission. The name of
the chargé d’affaires ad interim shall be notified, either by the head
of the mission or, in case he is unable to do so, by the Ministry for
Foreign Affairs of the sending State to the Ministry for Foreign
Affairs of the receiving State or such other ministry as may be
agreed.

In cases where no member of the diplomatic staff of the mission is present in the receiving State, a member of the administrative and
technical staff may, with the consent of the receiving State, be
designated by the sending State to be in charge of the current
administrative affairs of the mission.



Article 45 of the 1961 Convention is also relevant:

If diplomatic relations are broken off between two States, or if a
mission is permanently or temporarily recalled: (a) The receiving
State must, even in case of armed conflict, respect and protect the
premises of the mission, together with its property and archives; (b)
The sending State may entrust the custody of the premises of the
mission, together with its property and archives, to a third State
acceptable to the receiving State; (c) The sending State may entrust
the protection of its interests and those of its nationals to a third
State acceptable to the receiving State.

Article 15 of the 1963 Convention does contemplate the possibility of a temporary appointment and Article 13 of the 1963 convention contemplates the possibility of a provisional appointment, although these are not terribly well defined and still implicitly assume that there is a "sending State" for such temporary consuls.
